# Return the value in range, orelse return the specified value using data validation in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel, I want to return any value between 1 to 5 in a cell (say A1). If I enter '1' in A1, then it should return '1' in A1, if I enter '4' it should return '4'. But if I enter any number other than the numbers between 1 to 5, then the A1 cell should return '5'. I am able to do this by using the helper cell and 'if' formula. So that requires the usage of some other reference cell. What I want is to be reference cell and output cell should be same. I feel this can be done with the help of data validation (using custom and then using formula).

I tried inserting the formula `=if(and(A1>=1,A1<=5),A1,"5"`, it shows error and returns the previous value but not value '5'. How what formula should I use to do this or is there any other method to do this instead of data validation?

Comment: You can't have a formula and and input in the same cell. And data validation must be based on other cells or options typed manually if you use *list* option. So I would say what you want is not possible at all except you use macros and code somehting in the events of the worksheet.

Comment: You need VBA coding to do that.

Comment: Are you planning on using that cell somewhere else or is it just a visual thing? Because if the latter, simply use custom number format on A1, for example: `[<0]5;[<6]#;5`

Answer (score 0):

A simple vba code would do the trick

The code below will change the value if it s above 5 to 5. If it is not an integer it will then show an error message

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        
    If IsNumeric(target.Range("A1").Value) Then
    
        If target.Range("A1").Value >= 1 And target.Range("A1").Value <= 5 Then
        ElseIf target.Range("A1").Value >= 5 Then
            target.Range("A1").Value = 5
        End If
    
    Else
        MsgBox target.Range("A1").Value & "is not an integer"
    
    End If
End If

ERROR_HANDLER:
End Sub
```

Comment: The code works, but it is being applied to entire sheet instead of applying only to cell 'A1'.

Comment: oh yeah I missed that, that should be fixed :)

Comment: Wouldn't `Range(target.Address)` be the same as `target` ? @Pierre44 and you should be able to just use `target.Value` then if I'm not mistaken.